# How to remove Class diagram with lollipop interface shape invisible lines?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml, class-diagram

In Visual Studio 2010 Architect Class Diagram, when you choose to use the "lollipop" shape for interface implementation on a class, the designer seems to still have an invisible line that affects the rest of the diagram's relationships, e.g. it causes other lines to exhibit a "hump" to indicate two lines intersecting.

This is ok when both lines are visible but this seems to be a bug when using the lollipop. I would not expect other lines to be affected.

[image]

Is there a way to work aroun/remove this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bug. Could you submit this at http://connect.microsoft.com? Thanks!